# The forward rate and the connection with the future price of a zero coupon bond.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, finance, stochastic-analysis

In interest modelling we ahve the the simply compounded forward rate at time t over the interval $[T,S]$, where $t<T<S$ is defined as

$$1+f(t,T,S)(S-T)=\frac{P(t,T)}{P(t,S)}.$$

$P(t,T)$ is the price of a zero coupon bond at time $t$ with maturity $T$.

If $r$ is the short-rate, then we have that

$$P(t,T)=E_Q\left[\exp\left(-\int\limits_t^T r_sds\right)\Bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right],$$
for some suitable martingale measure $Q$, likewise for $P(s,T)$.

This means that
$$1+f(t,T,S)(S-T)=\frac{E_Q\left[\exp\left(-\int\limits_t^T r_sds\right)\Bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right]}{E_Q\left[\exp\left(-\int\limits_t^S r_sds\right)\Bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right]}.$$

It is now natural to look at the quantity $P(T,S)$. And we have

$$P(T,S)=E_Q\left[\exp\left(-\int\limits_T^S r_sds\right)\Bigg|\mathcal{F}_T\right].$$

What I am wondering is if there is a connection between $P(S,T)$ and $f(t,T,S)$?